# How to get inputs with append / prepend to have matching widths with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to have inputs that have append and/or prepend to all have matching widths?

Here's an example, but you can see that given multiple inputs with appends/prepends of various lengths, the will all end up being different widths, and it won't look very good.

http://jsfiddle.net/PLkfq/1/

Comment: This is an incredibly old answer, but if you're still having this problem, you might want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3434324/383609)

Comment: were you looking for a way to do it within bootstrap? (ie not setting a width elsewhere)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be pixel precise, forget classes and apply style to ids

add an id to the minutes span

```
<span id="minutes" class="add-on">minutes</span>
```

and use this bit of css

```
#service_name{width:200px;}
#service_duration{width:130px;}
#minutes{width:70px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/PLkfq/4/

Comment: Yeah, trying to avoid that tediousness.

Comment: @99miles You can create your own classes if you prefer or use jQuery to size the left input ( left input = full size input - span width) but there's no twitter bootstrap way if doing it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var normal_width = $("#service_name").width();
 var add_on = $(".add-on").width();
 var after_width = normal_width-add_on+3;
 $("#service_duration").width(after_width);
});
```

by this method you can set any size for your inputs

http://jsfiddle.net/PLkfq/25/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the class span1 on the append input, try using input-medium. The input width with be uniform but the append label will vary with the content size which seems ok. If you don't like that, you could set a min-width on the add-on class to make them all the same size.

http://jsfiddle.net/PLkfq/40/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="span12">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>

              <div class="control-group string required">
                <label class="string required control-label" for="service_name">
                  <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Service name</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input class="string required" id="service_name" name="service[name]" size="50" type="text">
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="control-group integer required">
                <label class="integer required control-label" for="service_duration">
                  <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Duration</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append">
                      <input class="numeric integer required input-medium" id="service_duration" name="service[duration]" type="text"><span class="add-on">minutes</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
                  <div class="control-group integer required">
                <label class="integer required control-label" for="service_sec">
                  <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Seconds</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append">
                      <input class="numeric integer required input-medium" id="service_sec" name="service[sec]" type="text"><span class="add-on">sec</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```